# Tomcat connector without using any executor (refer web.xml)

Tags: webserver, tomcat7, server.xml

My server.xml (on Tomcat 7) has a Connector which has maxThreads="100". The Connector doesn't reference any Executor, and there are no Executors defined. it looks like working well. Is it using the internal thread pool? If yes, what is the maximum number of threads that the internal thread pool support? Is there a disadvantage of using internal thread pool rather than one defined using Executor?